# Lenovo T400S microphone mute button doesn't work in Windows 7 RTM

Tags: audio, drivers, mute

The microphone mute button is not working on my T400s running Windows 7 RTM.  The speaker mute button works (when I press it the light comes on and sounds goes off).

When I click on the microphone button, the light doesn't come on and the microphones don't mute.  Is there a driver I am missing or something?  I can't find a driver for the button on Lenovo's site.

Anyone out there have this button working?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you discover that? I picture this funny moment where you muted the microphone and said something 'naughty' and it passed through after all...

Comment: In Windows  7, I thought the microphone always "listens", when you turn mute off, it feedbacks through the speakers. I am curious what you mean by mute, can you take a picture of the button / screenshot of the control as I haven't seen this before.

Comment: just noticed the light wasn't coming on.  I all ways double check my mute.

Answer (score 1):

Discovered this after quite some searching. Install (re-install if necessary) the Power Management Driver, at least v1.60 works for me. Reboot, and the microphone mute button should work. This seems to work on most Thinkpads (mine is a W510) on Windows 7.